# Resource not found with flavors with different applicationIds from package name

Tags: android, android-resources, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors, android-flavors

So my app has multiple flavors with an applicationId different from the package name. When i try to see if a layout contains an id it says it doesn't contain it, but it actually does only the path for the R file is the applicationId, and the one i use in code to check is the package name, this naturally leads to a different int. How do I solve this?

Basically my layout has the path: "applicationId:id/action_home"
And the one i use in my code is the one generated: "packagename:id/action_home"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more hours of looking around, it seems the issue is not with the resource, but with the debugger. it fails to find the resources but the code actually works. probably a studio/buildtools issue, leaving here the versions i am using in case someone wastes similar amounts of time on something so stupid:
Android Studio: 3.4 RC 2
Build Tools: 3.3.2